# Upgrade path from Sitecore 6.x to 6.6

Tags: sitecore

The site we are working on at the moment is using Sitecore 6.5 and we would like to upgrade it to 6.6 in order to test the new features that are available in that version.

Normally, Sitecore releases details describing how to upgrade from older versions but I can't find any such information for the 6.6 release. I'm assuming that this has to do with the fact that the release is still in Technical Preview.

We can install a clean version of the 6.6 CMS and build the code for our site over the top, but what we are hoping to find is a database update script and/or a Sitecore update package that includes all the new items in the 6.6 release.

Worst case we'll have to serialize our entire database as part of the upgrade but we were hoping to avoid having to do that due to the sheer size of the database.

Has anyone come across any upgrade details or do we have to wait until 6.6 comes out of Technical Preview?

Comment: Testing new features of the brand new release is always exciting, but I strongly recommend you not going live on technical preview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sitecore 6.6 has now been released and upgrade information is available on SDN [here](http://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%206/Update/6_6_0_rev_120918.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two possible solutions:

- Take empty 6.5 databases and compare them to empty 6.6 databases with some database compare tool. This way you can see what changed in 6.6 and make your own database update script
- Make a Sitecore package of your 6.5 database, including the content, layouts, templates that you created and install it in the 6.6 environment. This has worked for me with previous versions, so might work here too.

Comment: +1. I would go the second route personally. Sitecore Package is quite a unified interface to hide the differences. The DB schema changes might be a problem, but as far as I can see, only DMS database schema has been changed.

Comment: We'll end up either packaging our changes or serialising them if no upgrade packages are made available

Comment: Marked this as correct answer as if seems there are no official upgrade scripts available